# How does point-in-time restore to the exact second when Transaction Logs are taken every 10 minutes?

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-restore

When restoring a SQL Azure database, we have an option to restore it to an exact date **and time** within the recovery period, down to the exact second (e.g., 10:07:59 AM). How is this possible, when transaction log backups happen every 5-10 minutes?

Answer (score 2):

You have a log file in which Transaction log is written,this is the file which is getting backed up ..But you forgot the original log file which is still there and this helps in recovery to that very minute